# Merge a branch that has "chore(release): 2.1.0 [skip ci]" as last commit message doesn't trigger a release

Tags: github-actions, semantic-release

I'm trying out "semantic-release" scenarios, and if I create a `next` branch and publish a breaking change on that branch, the branch triggers a version `2.0.0`, which is good.

Now if I do a pull from the origin while I'm on the `next` branch, I get the last commit message generated by semantic release which is "`chore(release): 2.0.0 [skip ci]`".

All good so far.

Now I will checkout the "main" branch and then I merge the `next` branch on it.

What I expect to happen is that the main branch (which is on version 1.0.0) will see the changes coming from `next` branch and release a version `2.0.0` on the main `@release` channel.

But that doesn't happen for some reason, instead, there are no `action` or `release` triggered on github actions at all.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you merging the next branch to main? Is there a merge commit or something else? 

If the last commit contains [skip ci], it will not do anything of course.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing, the last commit has a [skip ci], but it did a fast forward merge, it didn't allow me to create a merge commit or anything.

Comment: So if the last commit contains [skip ci], that is the reason why it is not triggering anything..